# How to remove data from database?

Tags: php, cakephp

I have two table, BrokerInfo and BrokerBank in my database.  If data is saved in BrokerInfo then it will start the process to save data in BrokerBank table. If it is failed to save data in table 2 then it should remove data from table 1 in database. I am facing problem to remove data from table1 in database, how can i do it?
Here is my code for add action :

```
public function add() {
    if ($this->request->is('post'))
    {   

        $this->BrokerInfo->create();

            $this->BrokerInfo->save($this->request->data);
            $id=$this->BrokerInfo->getLastInsertId();
            $this->BrokerBank->begin();
            $this->BrokerBank->create();

            $this->request->data['BrokerBank']['broker_info_id'] = $id;

            if($this->BrokerBank->save($this->request->data))
            {   

                $this->BrokerInfo->commit();
                $this->redirect(array('action' => 'index'));
            }
            else 
            {   
                $this->BrokerInfo->rollback();              
                $this->Session->setFlash(__('The information could not be saved. Please, try again.'));
            }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Start the transaction

```
$this->BrokerBank->begin();
```

before you do anything. If the save fails, everything gets undone automatically. Currently you do the save for table1 before you start the transaction. And this means it does not get reverted in the rollback.